# content:attr(); not working in IE 10

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

For some reason, IE doesn't get the content: attr(data-title) as set below.
Works in FF and Chrome though.

How to fix this?

```
<a href="#" class="nav-roll">
            <span data-title="About">About</span> 
        </a>


    .nav-roll span:after {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #0198cd;
    color: #FFF;
    content: attr(data-title);
    display: block;
    padding: 0 2px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

You have not added a `<!DOCTYPE html>` to the top of your HTML file, forcing IE into Quirks Mode. IEQuirks does not support `:after` at all.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html> is included in the default.html

Comment: Do you have an `X-UA-Compatible` meta tag or HTTP header? Is your browser set to Compatibility Mode? Is there any content at all before the `<!DOCTYPE>`, even as innocent as a comment?

Comment: There nothing above <!DOCTYPE> 

My meta tag

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

Comment: The code works for me in IE 10, even in Quirks Mode (oddly enough). @user2184043, does the code fail for you when you test with just the code you posted, or is there something else on the page that might cause the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar issue, however was with a `<button>` element and not an anchor. Turns out it was nothing to do with the `attr(data-*)` in the end, the fix for me was to add `overflow: visible` onto the button itself.

Just leaving this here in case it may help anyone in the future.